# Where can I find a sample for Pcap for Diameter protocol (WireShark)?

Tags: pcap, wireshark-dissector, diameter-protocol

I was wondering if there are any sample wireshark pcaps for diameter protocol out there? If so please share.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one [sample capture](http://www.freediameter.net/trac/browser/VirtualTestbed/mrb/capture.pcap?rev=9e5a3c884de6a635f786aea3e97e7e99f701a022)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to take a look at the wireshark wiki regarding diameter, there a sample right there: https://wiki.wireshark.org/DIAMETER

Comment: Unfortunately NO Diameter pcap there :(

Answer (score 0):

It won't do you much good -- DIAMETER is the wrapper protocol.   Unlike RADIUS, where the entire packet is defined, leaving you with only the problem of decoding vendor specific attributes, DIAMETER dances around the actual AVPs themselves.   There is no "standard" the defines what those AVPs are, how they are encoded, if the DIAMETER messages are to be encrypted etc.

To pursue this, you'll need your DIAMETER endpoints and router message dictionaries.