# Anyone can post Diameter Protocol Sample Capture files

Tags: protocols, network-protocols, diameter-protocol

I am working on Diameter protocol, in the process of understanding the scope and functionality of protocol, I want some sample packets between diameter client-server.
    Can anyone can post.

Comment: This was answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097707/where-can-i-find-a-sample-for-pcap-for-diameter-protocol-wireshark